# Any suggestions on how to approach learning the Cocoa Touch API?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, xcode4

I'm an experienced programmer (C, a little C++, PHP, JavaScript) who is diving into developing for iOS. I have to say, while I get Objective-C with no problems, the Cocoa Touch API is massive, and quite complicated. Things that seem like they'd be simple, like dropping an annotated pin on a map, require several steps I would've never figured out without reading an example in a book.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to tackle learning this behemoth API. Let's say I wanted to figure out how to open a URL, fetch XML data from it, and parse it. How in the world would I even know where to begin (just an example, don't actually answer that)? I have Xcode 4, so I imagine the documentation must somehow make this relatively simple for me. I'm just new to this so I don't know where to start, so any advice would be stellar. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concentrate on the basics. Make sure that you read and fully understand the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html). If you read SO for a while, you'll find that a large percentage of iOS-related questions come from people who obviously haven't read that document. The funny thing is that it's really not that complicated -- the answers to memory questions here are almost always the same, and almost always answered by [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH).

Learn about the classes that are building blocks for the iOS apps. Know what UIResponder, UIView, UIControl, and UIViewController do, and how you can subclass them to do what you want. There are documents that explain all the important ideas, like [views](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [view controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html). Read those: getting a feel for where to find information in the documentation will help you be productive much more quickly. View controllers give an app its visible structure, so it's important to understand how your own view controller objects are managed by container view controllers like navigation controllers and tab bar controllers.

Understand the important patterns, too: MVC is the philosophy that will guide you; delegation is used all over the place; chain of responsibility is used to handle events. Once you get the patterns, parsing an XML file, providing data for a table, and dropping pins on a map all start to make sense in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to learn it effectively is writing code with it. It takes lots of effort primarily because Apples API:s requires a different mindset than most other API:s you are probably used to, especially if coming from a PHP or JavaScript background.

The first hurdle to overcome is you have to accept the fact that many things you otherwise take for granted now requires lots of more code which *you* must write. A few examples to clarify:

- If you're coming from PHP then you are used to SimpleXML which requires just a few lines of code to use. In iOS, there is a [SAX](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) parser which requires much more effort and complexity to use.
- For activity indicator, there is something akin to an [animated image](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIActivityIndicatorView) which you can use, but you have to add your own label and code to make sure you block user touch events while the spinner is running.
- If you want a nice colored non-default non-round-rect-white button, you have to code it yourself. It's not hard, but it's definitely not like creating a CSS file.

So most (seemingly) simple tasks requires much more effort than you are probably used to.

The next hurdle is to mentally detach yourself from Interface Builder. IB may seem alluring and tempting at first, but one often ends up writing the GUI more or less in code anyway. For instance: UIPopovers, Navigation bars, transitions, tables and custom toolbars etc.

Another hurdle is UINavigationBar. When you truly understand how that works, you've come a long way! I'm not saying it is bad, just that it is very different from what you are probably used to.

Don't be ashamed of asking questions here and use google. Just reading books about it won't help though.

Please not this is not a criticism of the platform. Quite the opposite as I personally am very fond of it and understand the reason why it works the way it does (most of the time). It is just that many programmers starting out with iOS development has very high expectations how easy it is to start working with it, and ends up getting burned or frustrated.

Comment: The negativism on display here is unnecessary and misguided. Creating buttons and progress indicators usually takes no code at all; parsing XML is very similar to using any other SAX-based parser. The advice to avoid IB is a disservice to the OP; neophytes often want to avoid IB because they don't understand it, but experienced developers rely on IB. There's rarely a reason to use UINavigationBar directly; let UINavigationController manage any nav bars for you and life will be much simpler.

Comment: @Caleb. Everything above is what lots of ppl experience diving into the platform for the first time. Ducking for that is being dishonest and only leads to frustration. For the record, I personally like the platform a lot. I work with it full time day-to-day. I don't want to get into a fanboy fight with you, so I've just updated my answer with some examples. Again: I really like it, but ppl coming from PHP or JavaScript are in for a rough (but fun) ride.

Comment: you've improved your post. There's always effort involved in adopting a new platform, whether that's PHP, Cocoa Touch, VB, or anything else. The OP seems already to have figured out that he's not in Kansas anymore, and the question now is "Where do I start?" not "How much is this gonna hurt?" I still think you're wrong to avoid IB because it doesn't do everything rather than embracing what it does well, but if that's how you feel so be it. No name calling necessary.

Comment: @Caleb: I never said to *avoid* IB, I said don't rely too much on it. As a beginner, it's easy to confuse IB with a complete tool for building GUI:s, many gets disappointed or give up when they realize most of the stuff has to be done in code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Stanford's excellent course [CS 193P](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/), "iPhone Application Development", is free in iTunes U.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about the course, but my question is more about how to handle so much information from a complex API, and how to go about figuring out how to tackle what I want to do in an app.